# how to have multiple Users in database with same RoleName when using membership?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

I`m using membership to authenticate users, i tried to specify a role for every registered user. for example I want to have 10 users with admin role, 100 users with User role. 
the problem is that the membership doesn't allow duplicate RoleName to add to data base. what should I do?

Comment: Have a table with one row per user and one row per role, with foreign key references to the Users table and the Roles table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to remove the unique constraint on the RoleName column.